# SwiftUI Custom Font based on selected language

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am building an app that support multiple languages, where users have the option to change the language at runtime if they wanted to.

We decided to use different fonts for different languages to provide a better visual consistency for the app and it was necessary since the app contain languages like (English, Arabic, Turkish, Kurdish, Persian, etc...).

The nearest solution that I have found for this is to use an ugly modifier like the following:

```
Text("txt_language")
    .if(language == "en") { view in
        view.font(.custom("bahij_bold", size: 14))
}
```

I am adding Multiple if modifier to the view and changing the font based on the selected language. However, I believe it's to messy and not really scalable.

Comment: Why not have a modifier/function that takes the language and returns the font for that language?

Comment: Not sure how to do that really could you give a simple example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a function. As we are dealing with fonts we'll create an extension on `Font` and create a function that will return the desired font for a given language.

It looks, from your question, that `language` is a `String`.

```swift
extension Font {
    static func customFont(for language: String) -> Font {
        switch language {
        case "en":
            return .custom("bahij_bold", size: 14)
        // Fill in the other fonts for the other languages that you want.
        default:
            return .body
        }
    }
}
```

Them we can use it in the following way:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    let language: String = "en"

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .font(.customFont(for: language))
    }
}
```